# What is a good way to receive_message_chain and and_wrap_original in RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I would like to mock this call:

```
headers[ 'REMOTE_ADDR' ]
```

It can be done with

```
allow_any_instance_of(RequestHandler).to 
  receive_message_chain(:headers, :[]) do |field|
    '1.2.3.4'
end
```

However, I would like a partial double, so only return the stubbed response if `field == 'REMOTE_ADDR'`. For other fields I want to call the original implementation.

According to [RSpec docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-4/docs/configuring-responses/wrapping-the-original-implementation),

```
expect(API).to receive(:solve_for).and_wrap_original { |m, *args| m.call(*args).first(5) }
```

However, this does not seem to work with message chain. I get:

```
undefined method `and_wrap_original' for #<RSpec::Mocks::Matchers::ReceiveMessageChain:0x007faef1f3fd20>
```

So, what is a good way to create this partial double in RSpec?

rspec-mocks 3.4.1

Comment: have you tried: `expect(headers).to receive(:[]).with( 'REMOTE_ADDR' ).and_return('1.2.3.4')` ?

Comment: Check out docs for mocking methods: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs

Answer (score 0):

For your particular case, you can rely on the `with` method to qualify the double based on the parameter passed:

```
allow_any_instance_of(RequestHandler).to receive_message_chain(:headers, :[]).with('REMOTE_ADDR').and_return('1.2.3.4')
```

Comment: Nope. This will execute and pass, but it does not actually test the `with` parameter. (as of rspec 3.10, at least) Change `REMOTE_ADDR` to anything else, and you'll see your test still (erroneously) passes.